# Защита от копипаста

Tags: защита, javascript

Пишу оригинальные описания радиостанций, а их копируют... Есть какой нибудь js код, чтобы не работал ctrl+C и выделение текста? Только выделение.

Comment: Как вариант может в картинку преобразовывать? Для серверного варианта на php вроде как есть функция ImageString(int im, int font, int x, int y, string s, int col);  А на js спасет только от нубовых копирастеров=) И еще предположение- сверху img прозрачный сделать, будет как витрина.

Comment: Тогда тексты не будут индексироваться..
только картинки..

Comment: Если текст индексируется, то копипастер всегда может просмотреть кэш поисковой системы и взять текст оттуда, независимо от того, какие защитные механизмы есть на сайте.

Comment: сама идея не имеет смысла, вам эту информацию всеравно надо как-то показывать, соответственно защититься от копипаста нельзя никак, даже если вы будете картинкой инфу показывать, даже если запретите выделение, если инфу нужно будет "украсть" - поверьте мне ее украдут и вы ничего с этим не поделаете...

Comment: К картинке можно приписать alt или title, тогда будут индексироваться, хотя это совсем уж защита от дурака, которому лень залезть в HTML. К такому-же методу защиты можно прибегнуть для того что-бы создать что-то подобное:

    <div class="no-cut">Текст который индексируется</div>

Стиль для этого:

    .no-cut {
        text-ident: -6000px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: url(файл_с_текстом_преобразовваным_в картинку.gif);
    }

Comment: А можно же определить, кто зашел на страницу робот или человек и если это человек стирать содержимое alt. Но опять же только cgi.

Answer (score 1):

Стиль `user-select: none;` или обработчик `onselectstart='return false;'`, например:

```
<div style='user-select: none;' onselectstart='return false;'>Текст</div>
```

Comment: Фигня, ибо есть F12

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать добавлять javascript'ом невидимый текст в названия. Копировать будет можно, но копироваться будет фигня. Плюс, в коде будет отображаться нормальное название радиостанции.

Скрипт:

```
$('.radio_name').each(function(){
    var h = this.innerHTML;
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*(h.length-1)) + 1;
    this.innerHTML = h.substr(0, pos) + '<span class="ht">text</span>' + h.substr(pos);
    // вместо text можно вставить результат генерации случайного слова
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="radio_name">Super radio 100500 FM</span>
<style>.ht{width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden}</style>
```

Comment: И еще генератор острой нецензурной брани прикрепить, круть!

Answer (score 1):

Открывать текст только роботам (я не знаю, насколько это правомерно и повлияет, но для роботов можно мешать слова, кроме ключевых - им же по барабану порядок слов). Не знаю, как это отразится на человековых проверках.

```
$words = explode(' ', $text);
shuffle($words);
$text = implode(' ', $words);
```

А для отображения - flash и

```
myTextField.selectable = false;
```

=) Декомпиляция флэша - это уже очень хороший уровень копирастера должен быть.

Ну и можно отморозиться - если вы юрлицо, вполне можно ставить копирайты и снимать по стопицот тыщ с сайтов-копирастов через суд.

*«Цель обороны - не уничтожить нападающего, а сделать нападение невыгодным»* ©

Comment: Идея с flash'ем понравилась, надо будет запомнить.

Answer (score 0):

Нет смысла запрещать выделение, это обходится - выключением поддержки js браузером.

Comment: Ну я думаю все зависит от уровня копирастера, абсолютный способ защитить информацию, это зашифровать ее. А все остальное так мелкие преграды.

Answer (score 0):

Должно сбрасывать все выделения в документе, не тестировал.

```
document.onmouseup = document.selection.clear;
```

Вместо документа предположу, можно использовать любой элемент

```
document.getElementById("id").selection.clear;
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы и помощь!!!